# Get names of column with max value for each row

Tags: r

i need your help, i have a data frame like this

```
int x  y  z
1   0  1  0
2   1  0  0
3   0  0  1
```

and the result that i need must be like this

```
int letter

1    y
2    x
3    z
```

my code is:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(samples)) 
    for(j in 1:ncol(samples)) 
        if(samples[i,][,j] == 1) print(c(i,names(samples[i,j])))
```

but it is not showing the second column and i need save in a new data.frame, any suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there are plenty of ways, but here's one:

```
samples <- read.table(text="int x  y  z
1   0  1  0
2   1  0  0
3   0  0  1",
header=TRUE)

#  int x y z
#1   1 0 1 0
#2   2 1 0 0
#3   3 0 0 1

data.frame(
 samples[1],
 letter=colnames(samples[-1][apply(samples[-1],1,which.max)])
)

#  int letter
#1   1      y
#2   2      x
#3   3      z
```

Comment: +1. You beat me to it. But my answer uses `names()[zzz]` instead of `colnames(zzz[])` and `zzz[,idx]` instead of `zzz[idx]`, so I'm going to leave it up!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `max.col`:

```
dat$newcol <- names(DF)[-1][max.col(DF[-1])]
```

This gives

```
  int x y z newcol
1   1 0 1 0      y
2   2 1 0 0      x
3   3 0 0 1      z
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416438/how-to-merge-multiple-variables-into-one-factor-variable) similar question.

```
tdf <- data.frame(
  A = c(1,1,0,0),
  B = c(0,0,1,0),
  C = c(0,0,0,1)
)

library(magrittr)

tdf %>%
  lapply(sum) %>%
  (function(x){
    a <- c()
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
      a <- c(a, rep(names(x[i]), x[i]))
    }
    return(a)
  })
```